# How to concatenate strings and ints natively?

Tags: go

The shortest (cleanest) way I have found so far to concatenate strings with ints in Go is the following:

```
"blahblah" + strconv.Itoa(42) + "something"
```

(importing package `strconv`)

Since one motto of the Go language is to be simple, I was surprised to have to import a package to do this.

Hence, my question: **is there any native (thus cleaner) way of doing this?**

---

Obviously, I tried the following syntax, which does not even compile:

```
"blahblah" + 42 + "something"
```

I also tried that one, which is in fact a cast of the value, which is not what I want (it converts the value to the corresponding unicode character, which would be `*` for the value 42):

```
"blahblah" + string(42) + "something"
```

Comment: strconv is native and clear way to do this, otherway you're relaying on some auto-conversion from int to string, which could be misleading and provide you less flexibility

Comment: Have a look at http://golang.org/src/strconv/itoa.go and extract the functionality you want. The `formatBits()` function on line 62 does most of the heavy lifting, but can handle integers represented in many bases. You should be able to simplify it for your needs.

Comment: @Intermernet Thanks for the suggestion, but I am rather looking for the standard way of doing this in go, as I am quite new to this language, and because I couldn't believe `Itoa` was the most practical way.

Comment: On "how is this even thinkable when Go seeks to be simple"--by "simple" the designers didn't mean wanted to have your code be absolutely short as possible (and often designers answer questions on the lists with, roughly, "just write out a comple more lines"). You'll have to do things you're not used to having to do if you come from Python, Perl, etc. Rather they mean the *spec* is understandable and it's feasible to follow what the machine does to run your code you give it. That includes a lack of implicit conversions à la C++ or JS, which is what's biting you here.

Comment: To the specific question `strconv` or `fmt` seem fine to me, according to which looks better in context.

Comment: @Lashane I guess you're unfortunately right. It is so weird that they didn't include some shortest way of doing this in the language design.

Comment: @twotwotwo fair enough, I guess I'll have to distinguish between short and simple.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? Please care to explain, so that I can rectify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do the trick (it uses reflection though):

```
str := fmt.Sprintf("blah %d blah", 42)
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that one, but IMO in some cases this is less readable than a plain `+` operator.

Comment: I guess I'll go for that one anyway, it looks like the cleanest way without any extra dependency.

Comment: Well, you do have to import the `fmt` package. But I've seen this technique used many times over.

Comment: Yes, but that imports the `fmt` package. I think @Joffrey is looking for a way to do this with no imports at all.

Comment: @Intermernet It's true, that was my first goal, but I think this is impossible (even though I would love to be proven wrong). But anyway, I believe I already import the `fmt` package almost everywhere, at least for some debug logging, so it does not really add anything.

Comment: @Joffrey If you're already importing the `fmt` package then you may as well use that method. See my comment under your question for a way to do this with no imports, but it involves replicating the code from the strconv package, so it's not really practical.

Answer (score -1):

You can use different print commands to do what you want. It's not a one liner, but it works.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Print("blahblah")
    fmt.Print(42)
    fmt.Print("something")
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ArnMC-UyZW)

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to build a string, in particular in the `String()` method. Your solution prints to the console.